# This is undefined when simulating click event using shallow wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate the click event and test the logic inside the handler which accesses this.props and this.context, but I see this as undefined. Can someone please help what is that I'm doing wrong

React component

```
export default class NavButton extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.context.router.history.push(this.props.navigateTo);  
    }

    render() {
        const {
            navigationText,
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="vx_btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    {navigationText}
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Test Case

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import NavButton from './navButton';

const context = {
  router: {
    history: {
      push: jest.fn()
    }
  }
};
const props = {
  navigateTo: '/navigateTo',
  navigationText: 'Next'
};

describe('#handleClick', () => {
  it('should navigate', async () => {
    const navBtnWrapper = shallow(<NavButton {...props }/>, { context});
    const button = navBtnWrapper.find('button');
    button.simulate('click', { preventDefault() {} });
    expect(context.router.history.push).toBeCalledWith('/navigateTo');
  });
});
```

Test case fails, and this is undefined when I console output.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes.

```
render() {
     const {
         navigateTo,
         navigationText
     } = this.props;
```

`onClick={() => this.handleClick()}`

`this.context.router.history.push(this.props.navigateTo)`

Comment: Tried, this is still undefined.

Comment: have you try adding `navigateTo` in props declaration in render().